# AWS beanstalk deployment error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have little problems with deploying an application.
I have an PHP environment. I have uploaded an .zip file in it containing 3 files - one.php, two.html and three.html. The problem is when I click on the environment URL also on my pure domain example.com I get the following error: 
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

However when I type the address with its extension, for example environmentURL/one.php or example.com/one.php it works great.

Can someone help me with this please. Why I'm unable to access my app via its first primary page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access your app via primary page because your app is missing an index. Add an index file (`index.php` or `index.html`) to your zip bundle and it should work.

Comment: Thanks,it works this way. An index file needs to be created.